# WiX CustomActionData is empty in called CustomAction

Tags: c#, wix, wix3.5, custom-action

once again I'm stuck at a problem, that is probably easy to solve.
I want to extend a setup, created with WiX, to make changes in the configuration file of the installed program. In order to do this I've created a **CustomAction**. To be able to change the configuration file, I need to know the (install-)location of it within my **CustomAction**. Therefore I try passing the **INSTALLLOCATION** and Filename to my **CustomAction**. Here lies the problem: The **CustomActionData**-Attribute is always empty and the setup throws an exception.

My CustomAction is a C# DLL file: `DemoDatumErzeugen.CA.dll`. It contains a method `DatumEintragen` which modifies the configuration file. I'm trying to access the data  this way:

```
string path = session.CustomActionData["LOCATION"];
```

This is where the exception is thrown. I only got the German error message, but it says something along the lines: `The supplied key was not found in the dictionary` (`Der angegebene Schlüssel war nicht im Wörterbuch angegeben.`).

This is how I try passing the properties from my setup-script to my custom action:

```
<Binary Id="DemoDatumEinrichtenCA" SourceFile="DemoDatumErzeugen.CA.dll"/>

<CustomAction Id="DemoDatum.SetProperty" Return="check" Property="DatumEintragen" Value="LOCATION=[INSTALLLOCATION];NAME=StrategieplanConfig.xml;"/>
<CustomAction Id="DemoDatum" BinaryKey="DemoDatumEinrichtenCA" DllEntry="DatumEintragen" Execute="deferred" Return="check" HideTarget="no"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="DemoDatum.SetProperty" After="InstallFiles"/>
  <Custom Action="DemoDatum" After="DemoDatum.SetProperty"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I've seen many examples where it was done the same way or at least very similar. I've tried many things but nothing seems to help like changing the value After in `<Custom Action="DemoDatum.SetProperty" After="InstallFiles"/>`. CustomActionData is always zero.
I check it with: `session.CustomActionData.Count`
Once again I'm pretty thankful for any help or hints where I've done something wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `Property` attribute value of `DemoDatum.SetProperty` should be equal to the `Id` attribute value of the deferred action. So, either change the property name to `DemoDatum`, or change the `Id` of the deferred action to `DatumEintragen`.

Comment: Indeed! That was it. Thank you alot. It's easy to overlook.

Comment: @Yan Sklyarenko I am facing a problem during the installation of my .exe created using bootstraper application.Can you please look into this SO  and help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151665/error-0x80070643-fatal-error-during-installation-wix