# Is it possible to set property in Deferred custom action in WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, custom-action

is it possible to set a property in Deferred custom action.If so please suggest me the way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar dilemma few weeks back. And this is what was told to me by seniors.

Deferred Custom action cannot directly modify installer properties.
But there is an workaround: you can use **immediate custom action** to set the property.Also you could use **CustomActionData** to store property value and then use it in C# or VB.net Custom Actions.

I think this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233267/how-to-pass-customactiondata-to-a-customaction-using-wix)  might help you.