# Visual Studio 2017 C# installer project is not installing my app

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2017, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have been having troubles with this, hope you can help, I have developed an app using c#, now it's time to deploy, I have recently installed the plugin to create an installer project in my solution, so I followed the steps to create the installer and then compile the project, and everything is fine until that point, the plugin created an installer, so I ran the installer and used the default to folder to install the app, but when I go to check to the default folder installation, the folder doesn't exist, also I tried by putting the folder path by myself, same result as before, is there anyone else with the same problem as me?
could some of you give me a link where I can see a full guide of how to create an installer using c#?

Comment: You need to tell us the architecture of your setup (32/64 bit), the exact default folder you expect to find your code in (and is it Application Folder?). And did you add files or project output to that folder? And is it a install for Everyone setup or Just me? And are you an admin on the system?

Comment: Did you get this sorted?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: I am wondering if you have a `32/64-bit` folder issue:

- `C:\Program Files\`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\`

Check both to see if you see your installed folder.

---

It is not clear what tutorial, if any, you have used so far. [There are some youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpqQVpFfFN8) ([search](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%202017%20Installer%20Projects)). Please remember to add enough information to your question to ensure that we understand what tutorials or learning material you have tried, or our answers become too generic and sometimes ridiculously irrellevant for the problem at hand..

There are many alternative tools you can use to build an installer. **[The Visual Studio Installer Project feature](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) is very limited, I never use it**. There are several alternatives, both free such as [**WiX**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864) (good, free and capable - with a learning curve) and commercial tools such as **Installshield** and **Advanced Installer** (faster and easier, but costs money).

***I will just link to a few previous answers to see if it helps you find a deployment tool that suits you***: [**Various Deployment Tools**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840). Further, similar links below.

---

Some Further Links:

- [How to create windows installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624070/how-to-create-windows-installer/49632260#49632260) (links to Windows Installer tools and legacy setup tools on top)
- [Wrap C# application in .msi installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343445/wrap-c-sharp-application-in-msi-installer/50348142#50348142)
- [one installer for 3 programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532378/one-installer-for-3-programs/50536168#50536168)
- [Cancelling a Windows service installation/Uninstallation with the Windows Installer causes service to be incompletely installed/uninstalled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50436787/cancelling-a-windows-service-installation-uninstallation-with-the-windows-instal/50438190#50438190)
- [Cannot call command.exe(SQL Server Setup.exe) while calling C# CA with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322581/cannot-call-command-exesql-server-setup-exe-while-calling-c-sharp-ca-with-para/50429461#50429461)